# Single Sign-on VS Reduced Sign-On

Tags: single-sign-on

By using single sign-on, users can login once and gains access to all systems without being prompted to login again at each of them. But how reduced sign-on works? What is the aim of reduced sign-on and its uses?

Comment: I just heard the term reduced sign on. What is that?

Comment: I also don't know. That's why i asked it here.

Answer (score 1):

Reduced sign-on adds another verification mechanism on top of Kerberos.

> Reduced Sign On: This concept handles the above scenario by prompting another set of verification when you try to access critical applications. This extra layer of authentication could be any one of below list:
>
> 1) Challenge Question
>
> 2) Digital Certificate
>
> 3) Hardware Token number
>
> 4) Smart Card
>
> 5) Biometrics
>
> Reducing users' sign-on complexity problems requires a balance between user satisfaction and security. If the scale swings too far toward security when trying to prevent a breach, user satisfaction decreases. Similarly, if the scale swings toward user satisfaction, you can compromise IT security.

See [here](http://identitycontrol.blogspot.de/2007/07/single-sign-on-reduced-sign-on.html) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

### Single Sign-On (SSO)

SSO is a mechanism for users to enter a single set of credentials to logon to multiple applications.

### Reduced Sign-On (RSO)

RSO is a mechanism intended to reduce the frequency with which users are prompted to provide credentials for authentication.

---

### Difference

While the usage of both terms have been intertwined, there are distinct conceptual differences:

> 1. While a user needs to authenticate to his workstation in SSO, RSO requires an additional authentication to each critical application.
> 2. To implement SSO, you must deploy an SSO product and customize it to the systems in the envrionment. For RSO, a combination of password
>      synchronization and centralized authentication solutions is
>      implemented.
> 3. While SSO authenticates based on password authentication, RSO usually uses more than one type of authentication mechanism in higher
>      risk applications; i.e. digital certificates, security tokens, smart
>      cards, biometrics. RSO provides a way to reduce the number of
>      authentication processes for users, typically to two factors of
>      authentication.
>
> In layman's term, unlike SSO where a user logs on just one time, RSO 
>   challenges the user again for higher risk applications while keeping
>   the frequency of authentication low.
>
> There's no "better" option between the two; it really depends on the
>   requirements and nature of systems/applications.

---

### Reference

1. [What does SSO mean to you?](http://blog.identityautomation.com/blog/2012/sso-mean)
2. [Non-technical explanation](http://itsecformanagers.com/2014/08/07/a-not-so-technical-discussion-about-single-sign-on-sso-and-reduced-sign-on-rso/)
3. [Reduced Sign-On](http://hitachi-id.com/resource/concepts/reduced-sign-on.html)
4. [Single Sign-On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)